# How to get the children of specific parent? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var subtypechecked = function() {
  var subtype = $(this);
  var evidence = subtype.parent().parent().parent().children("input[name^='Regression.']").fadeOut();
  alert(evidence.context.name);

};
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", subtypechecked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel panel-default"></div>
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix"></div>
  <div style="padding-left:15px;padding-top:5px"></div>
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Repression">Repression
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Repression.Confirmed">Repression.Confirmed
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="Unknown.Confirmed">Unknown.Confirmed
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get all elements with name begin with "Repression.". However, I checked in the firebug. "evidence" is the button I clicked. That make no sense.

Comment: Please be more specific what the objective is. Your traverse doesn't make sense and neither does the alert. You also don't have any elements with that name ...there is a typo in the selector ...`Regression != Repression`

Comment: Why are you using `.context`?  http://api.jquery.com/context/

Comment: When you do `.parent().parent().parent()`, that is bound to break and very hard to read. Use `closest(selector)` to find the ancestor. In your case `closest(".row")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://api.jquery.com/children/
>
> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

You are executing `.children` on your `.row` div, .children only looks at the direct desendants, you are wanting to use .find which will look deeper in the dom tree for elements.

```
var evidence = subtype.parent()
              .parent()
              .parent()
              .find("input[name^='Repression.']").fadeOut();
```

Also you are using Repression not Regression for names

Comment: However, it still is not what I want. I want to fadeout not only checkbox, but also the word behind it.

Comment: @RunpengChen, _'I want to get all elements with name begin with "Repression."'_, then you need to actually say what you want in the question. Also if that is what you want then use the proper selector, so it sounds like you actually want to fade out the label and the checkbox so it would be: `label.checkbox-inline` since the label contains the text and the checkbox element

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with `context`. Quoting jQuery doc, the context is:

> The DOM node context originally passed to jQuery(); if none was passed then context will likely be the document.

So it will return the original DOM passed to jQuery, which is the clicked checkbox, because your selector doesn't find any element matching your query.

You could use `parents` and `find` instead:

```
var subtypechecked = function() {
  var subtype = $(this);
  var evidence = subtype.parents('.row')
                 .find("input[name^='Repression.']");

  alert(evidence.attr('name'));

  // fadeOut the parent label to hide the text, as requested
  evidence.parent().fadeOut();

};
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", subtypechecked);
```

Comment: However, it still is not what I want. I want to fadeout not only checkbox, but also the word behind it.

Comment: See updated snippet, i've added a line to fadeOut parent label of the checkbox to hide the text